# How to use change_presence at on_ready event? (discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I've read online that using `change_presence` at the `on_ready` event could cause your Discord bot to be banned due to rate limiting. I presume this is because a lot of API calls are made during this event.

My current solution is to use `asyncio.sleep()` at the start of the event in the hope that the initialisation API calls are made first and then, after a period of time, my code runs.

I'm now wondering whether this actually does anything to help, or if it's just as bad as having no sleep whatsoever?

Code below:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await self.bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="❌"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to just pass it in when constructing your bot. Example:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix="!",
    activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="❌"),
    intents=discord.Intents.default(),
)
```