# Discord.py presence using app_commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands

class Bot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        intents = discord.Intents.all()
        super().__init__(command_prefix = ";", intents = intents)
    
    async def setup_hook(self):
        await self.tree.sync()
        await self.Bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="Commands"))
        print("Synced slash commands for Kurumi")


client = Bot()
```

I need help on how I can change the presence of the bot. I am new to using the new slash commands/app_commands so how can I change the presence with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use change\_presence at on\_ready event? (discord.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72847603/how-to-use-change-presence-at-on-ready-event-discord-py)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change the presence of the bot in `on_ready` or `setup_hook`, instead, pass it in directly when instantiating the bot. It will immediately take effect and stay there.

See [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.activity) and [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client).

```py
def __init__(self):
    intents = discord.Intents.all()
    activity = discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="Commands")
    super().__init__(command_prefix=";", intents=intents, activity=activity)
```

Comment: and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72847603/how-to-use-change-presence-at-on-ready-event-discord-py) :p